# Krusader can't go into archives

Tags: 12.04, kde4, krusader

I installed Krusader to my ubuntu from repos with "apt-get install" and it work fine except one thing - i can not enter in any archives. While trying to do so it says - "**listing folders is not supported for protocol kio_krarc**". In settings/archives tab i see "zip" and anything else selected. I clicked "auto configure" and see those archives are "enabled" but still have no luck. I can't imagine normal work without going into archives. Can i somehow fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is bug in krusader: [launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/krusader/+bug/1065110)

Problem is solved krusader 2.4.0-beta3: [deb](https://launchpad.net/~ladislav.bonita/+archive/precise-backports/+packages)

Comment: Thanks god you answered. I remove current krusader and installed it from this deb and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Install the newest version of the Krusader (2.4.0 beta3), available here, for [32-bit](https://launchpad.net/~ladislav.bonita/+archive/precise-backports/+build/3935250) and 64-bit pc's.